# How to add Leaflet.Locate to an R made map (instead of locate)

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I was looking into this [repo](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol), where a blue dot is added to your leaflet map, that if you open it on a phone, it follows you as you walk, similar to a google maps option, as shown in [this demo](https://domoritz.github.io/leaflet-locatecontrol/demo/).

Usually in R and using Rmd, I would have this code so that I can know where I am on the map:

---

### title: "Test map"
output: html_document

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(leaflet)
```

### Old map.locate option

I usually made this maps for the field

```
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(-71.0382679, 42.3489054, zoom = 18) %>% 
  addEasyButton(easyButton(
    icon="fa-crosshairs", title="Locate Me",
    onClick=JS("function(btn, map){ map.locate({setView: true, enableHighAccuracy: true }); }")))
```

That works great for finding your location, but it does not generate a marker where you are, and more importantly, it does not follow you around, you can see an example of that [here](https://derek-corcoran-barrios.github.io/InteractiveMaps/TestLocate.html)

### Trying to incorporate control.locate

So my first try was just to change *locate* for *control.locate*, but that did not work.

```
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(-71.0382679, 42.3489054, zoom = 18) %>% 
  addEasyButton(easyButton(
    icon="fa-crosshairs", title="Follow Me",
    onClick=JS("function(btn, map){ map.control.locate()}")))
```

I am still thinking of other options, but any help would be welcome, here is the [full rmd in github](https://github.com/derek-corcoran-barrios/derek-corcoran-barrios.github.io/blob/master/InteractiveMaps/TestLocate.Rmd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These GPS features have been implemented in the [*leaflet.extras* package](https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras).

Here's a working version based on your MWE

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

your_map <- leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(-71.0382679, 42.3489054, zoom = 18) %>%
  addControlGPS(
    options = gpsOptions(
      position = "topleft",
      activate = TRUE, 
      autoCenter = TRUE,
      setView = TRUE))

activateGPS(your_map)
```

The results looks like this:

[image: Flowers in Chania]

*Spoiler*: Chrome thinks I'm in São Paulo right now... (where I'd rather be!)

...and [here](https://mca91.github.io/leaflet-current-pos/)'s a working demo on my Git.

Work's like a charm on my mobile.