# How can I build an app in R that shows in a map the geolocation of the user?

Tags: r, shiny, geolocation, r-leaflet

I am brand new to [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) and [leaflet](/questions/tagged/leaflet) and need your help, please. I want to build an app in [r](/questions/tagged/r) that shows in a leaflet map the geolocation of the user. It seems easy, however I couldn't deploy the app.

I started with an [example code](https://github.com/Ponsoda/geoprogramming-youtube/blob/main/FirstScript/R/GettingStartedWithShiny.R) to build a map using leaflet and shiny that runs well:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = -48.465, lat = -27.55, zoom = 12) %>% 
      addMarkers(lng = -48.465, lat = -27.55)
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Then, I tried to add some lines of JS code (I find [here](https://github.com/AugustT/shiny_geolocation)) to have access to the geolocation of the user. These code lines are below:

```
tags$script('
  $(document).ready(function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

    function onError (err) {
    Shiny.onInputChange("geolocation", false);
    }
    
   function onSuccess (position) {
      setTimeout(function () {
          var coords = position.coords;
          console.log(coords.latitude + ", " + coords.longitude);
          Shiny.onInputChange("geolocation", true);
          Shiny.onInputChange("lat", coords.latitude);
          Shiny.onInputChange("long", coords.longitude);
      }, 1100)
  }
  });
')
```

On my last try, I executed:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(

    tags$script('
      $(document).ready(function () {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
        function onError (err) {
          Shiny.onInputChange("geolocation", false);
        }
        function onSuccess (position) {
          setTimeout(function () {
            var coords = position.coords;
            console.log(coords.latitude + ", " + coords.longitude);
            Shiny.onInputChange("geolocation", true);
            Shiny.onInputChange("lat", coords.latitude);
            Shiny.onInputChange("long", coords.longitude);
          }, 1100)
        }
      });
    '),

    leafletOutput("mymap")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Observador reativo para os inputs de geolocalização
  observe({
    # Se geolocation for TRUE, renderize o mapa
    if (input$geolocation) {
      # Cria um mapa com a biblioteca leaflet
      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        setView(lng = input$long, lat = input$lat, zoom = 12) %>%
        addMarkers(lng = input$long, lat = input$lat) %>%
        # Renderize o mapa
        renderLeaflet(output, "mymap")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, it does not work. I got the following message:

```
Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero
  47: observe [#5]
  46: <observer>
   3: runApp
   2: print.shiny.appobj
   1: <Anonymous>
```

Can you help me? What is wrong?
Thank you in advance;
Marcio.

Comment: You don't need to hard code this in JS. Check the package `leaflet.extra` if you want to stick with JS without extra packages check the function `AddEasyButton()`. More info at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68998723/how-to-add-leaflet-locate-to-an-r-made-map-instead-of-locate

Comment: Thanks, @G.Cocca. I tried now, but the marker is far from my actual position. I think it's not a problem with the code. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Thet's weired. However it's challenging to guess what the problem is. You should provide the piece of code to dig further in

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because `input$geolocation` is initially `NULL`. The app below works at condition that you run it in a true browser that will ask you to allow access to your geolocation. It doesn't work in the RStudio browser. I added a button.

Also, `... %>% renderLeaflet(output, "mymap")` is not correct. You have to render a leaflet in an output slot:

```r
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles()
  })
```

then you can manipulate it with the help of `leafletProxy("mymap")`.

The app:

```r
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$script('
      $(document).ready(function () {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
        function onError (err) {
          Shiny.onInputChange("geolocation", false);
        }
        function onSuccess (position) {
          setTimeout(function () {
            var coords = position.coords;
            console.log(coords.latitude + ", " + coords.longitude);
            Shiny.onInputChange("geolocation", true);
            Shiny.onInputChange("lat", coords.latitude);
            Shiny.onInputChange("long", coords.longitude);
          }, 1100)
        }
      });
    '),

  actionButton("go", "Go to geolocation"),
  
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles()
  })

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    if(input$geolocation) {
      leafletProxy("mymap") %>%
        setView(lng = input$long, lat = input$lat, zoom = 12) %>%
        addMarkers(lng = input$long, lat = input$lat)
    } else {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Geolocation unavailable",
        "Have you allowed the browser access to your geolocation?"
      ))
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```